# What is the name of ** in python?

Tags: python, operators, type-conversion

When programming Python I sometimes do a `**` to make a conversion. I understand what it does but what data structures am I manipulating? A `dict` and what is the other? An `array`? Is there a name for the `**` operator?

Comment: exponential operator?

Comment: There are two meanings for `**`.  Power and "keyword argument dictionary".  Which are you talking about?  The documentation has these words: " If the form “**identifier” is present, it is initialized to a new dictionary receiving any excess keyword arguments, defaulting to a new empty dictionary."  Which of them seem relevant to your question?

Comment: "keyword argument dictionary" was the one I'm asking about. Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It's not an operator as such, so it doesn't *really* have a name, but [it is defined as a "syntactic rule"](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions). So it should be called:

- "the keyword argument unpacking syntax"

If you have a list of arguments, `*args`, it's called **"argument unpacking"**, in the same manner `**kwargs` is called **"keyword argument unpacking"**.

If you use it on the left hand side of an `=`, as in `a, *middle, end = my_tuple`, you'd say **"tuple unpacking"**.

In total, there are three types of (single parameter) arguments:

```
def f(x)  # x: positional argument
def f(x, y=0)  # y: keyword argument
def f(x, *xs, y=0)  # y: keyword-only argument
```

The `*args` argument is called the "variable positional parameter" and `**kwargs` is the "variable keyword parameter".
Keyword-only arguments can't be given positionally, because a variable positional parameter will take all of the arguments you pass.

Most of this can be found in PEPs [0362](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/) and [3102](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/), as well as in the [Control Flow](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html) section of the docs. It should be noted though that the function signature object PEP is only a draft, and the terminology might just be one person's idea. But they are good terms anyway. :)

So the `*` and `**` arguments just unpack their respective data structures:

```
args = (1, 2, 3)  # usually a tuple, always an iterable[1]

f(*args) → f(1, 2, 3)

# and 

kwargs = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}  # usually a dict, always a mapping*

f(**kwargs) -> f(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

[1]: Iterables are objects that implement the `__iter__()` method and mappings are objects that implement `keys()` and `__getitem__()`. Any object that supports this protocol will be understood by the constructors `tuple()` and `dict()`, so they can be used for unpacking arguments.

Comment: In case anyone else is confused, `def f(x, *xs, y=0): pass` is not valid Python 2.{5,6,7} syntax, nor does `def f(x, y=0, *xs):` do what you might expect. AFAIK, the only way to achieve the (obviously) intended effect is `def f(x, *xs, **kw): y=kw.get('y', 0); del kw; ...`. Python 3 handles the original syntax as expected.

Comment: While we're at it: the `begin, *middle, end = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` syntax doesn't work in Python 2.x either.

Comment: This answer is incorrect in Python 3.5 and later. 
PEP-448 specifies the ** operator as the dictionary unpacking operator. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/

Answer (score 13):

I don't think it has a name. In the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) under "Unpacking Argument Lists", it's just referred to as "the `**`-operator."

I'm not sure what you mean by "the other" data structure. When you do `f(**kwargs)` you unpack the dictionary `kwargs` as a sequence of key-value pairs. I don't see that there's another structure involved.

I'll copy the [example](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the above documentation for clarity.

```
>>> def parrot(voltage, state='a stiff', action='voom'):
...     print "-- This parrot wouldn't", action,
...     print "if you put", voltage, "volts through it.",
...     print "E's", state, "!"
...
>>> d = {"voltage": "four million", "state": "bleedin' demised", "action": "VOOM"}
>>> parrot(**d)
-- This parrot wouldn't VOOM if you put four million volts through it. E's bleedin' demised !
```

See also: [What does *args and **kwargs mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/287085/817630)

Comment: There are several possible ways a reader may interpret `f(**kwargs)`...

Answer (score 3):

If you are unsure what to call a particular operator or if it is unnamed, you can always resort to [Waka Waka Bang Splat](http://babek.info/libertybasicfiles/lbnews/nl123/fun.htm) as a reference to help you figure out what to call it. In this case for `**` I would call it `double-splat`, though there are some [alternate names for symbols](http://www.codejacked.com/know-your-keyboard-bang-splat-whack/).